# Can I give my Google Drive files edit permission in my iOS app but make those files invisible or view only in a browser

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api

After my iPhone app user Signs In using the standard Google Drive sign in GTMOAuth2ViewController, I want my app to be able to view and edit the Google Drive files.  But I don't want users to be able to edit, replace, or remove those same files using a browser.  Is it possible to set up permissions to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the application data folder: https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata?hl=en  This might do what you want.